# Problem with map in Flutter when connecting to firebase

Tags: flutter, dart

I have the class Record3 which gets the data from my cloud firestore:

```
class Record3 {
  final String name;
  final int ref;
  final bool display;
  final DocumentReference reference;

  Record3.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map, {this.reference})
      : assert(map['name'] != null),
        assert(map['ref'] != null),
        assert(map['display'] != null),
        name = map['name'],
        ref = map['ref'];
        display = map['display'];


  Record3.fromSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot snapshot)
      : this.fromMap(snapshot.data(), reference: snapshot.reference);

  @override
  String toString() => "Record<$name:$ref:$display>";
}
```

I added the field `display` to the cloud firestore and now I am trying to add it into the record3 code. However, there is an issue with the line `display = map['display'];`. `display` throws the error:

```
The name 'display' is already defined.
Try renaming one of the declarations.
```

And `map` throws the error:

```
Undefined name 'map'.
Try correcting the name to one that is defined, or defining the name.
```

I'm not too sure how to fix these errors as both are defined so I have a feeling its something to do with adding `display` and not having changed variables in map? I'm not sure though so any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the line before display assignment to `ref = map['ref'],` with a comma instead of the semicolon.

Comment: I can't believe that's what I was missing haha, thank you!!